# Why can't I upload in ftp server? (Only in IE, this code works with other browsers)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Specifically the browsers that I mentioned that works with the code I am using is this: Opera, Mozilla, & Google Chrome. But on IE, and ME I get this error.

```
550 No Such File or Directory
```

While on the 3 browsers that I had mentioned this code works well, when I use the input type = "file", when I tried catching the error before without using the Web Exception, I got the error on line 37 which has this code

```
  Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <input type="file" id="fuAttachment" runat="server"/>
       <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
  try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.  
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://url/" + fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName + "");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.  
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.  

            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Response.Write("File Successfully Uploaded");
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException a)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)a.Response).StatusDescription;
            Response.Write(status);
        }
```

What do I have to do to fix this problem? I don't think that I should be asking for the administrator to change the ftp settings, because this application works on the other browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

IE sends the client's full path and filename, whereas other browsers send something like "C:\fakepath\filename". You should not rely on `PostedFile.FileName` being a valid file name.

`<input type="file">` requires (used to require?) `enctype='multipart/form-data'` as attribute of the containing `<form>`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/21336)

Comment: so instead of PostedFile.FileName what do you suggest that I should use? also, I did enctype=multipart/form-data in my form it still has the same error.

I did try removing the fuattachment.postedfile.filename and changed it to a string "a" and it works.

Comment: "sanitize user input": You cannot rely on the file name provided by the browser. use `Path.GetFilename()` to extract the pure filename, handle characters not supported by OS.

Comment: Okay, I used substring to extract the file name from the fuattachment.posted.filename, thanks a lot for the advise, it really helped me.

Comment: but I think I'll with Path.Getfilename since I got an error when I am using Google Chrome now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [these options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323446/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-use-both-the-ftp-port-mode-and-t)?

**How to change the Internet Explorer FTP Client mode**

1. Start Internet Explorer.
2. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
3. Click the Advanced tab.
4. Under Browsing, click to clear the Enable folder view for FTP sites check box.
5. Click to select the Use Passive FTP (for firewall and DSL modem compatibility) check box.

It could be that the other browsers are set to use passive mode and IE isn't or vice versa

Comment: I tried the solution that you suggested, but I still got the same error. "Use Passive FTP" by default is checked, Also "Enable folder view" but I cleared it as it was suggested.